# for loop is only working for first expect value after commenting expect its working fine. am i doing anything wrong here?

Tags: javascript, json, neo4j

for loop is only working for first expect value after commenting expect its working fine. am i doing anything wrong here?

```
let a = validNodeQuery.response[0].n.latest

    console.log(a)
    console.log(a.length)
    let max = a.length
   
    for(let i=0; i< max; i++)
    {  
        let value = a[i];
        console.log(value);
        let pxlatest = `validNodeQuery.response[0].n.p${value}Latest`;
        console.log(pxlatest);
        expect(pxlatest).to.equal(true);
    }
```

Comment: You'll want something like `pxlatest = validNodeQuery.response[0].n["p" + value + "Latest"]`